# can not read get property of undefined angular 2 error

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3, typescript, maps, angular

hi I am trying to get city name from google api but getting that error below is my code

appcomponent class

```
 import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
    import {marketComponent} from './market.component';
    import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
    import {introComponent} from './intro.component';
    import {geoService} from './service.geo';
    import {JSONP_PROVIDERS}  from 'angular2/http';
    declare var google: any;
    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
        directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
        providers: [JSONP_PROVIDERS, geoService]
     })
    @RouteConfig([
        { path: '/intro', name: 'Intro', component: introComponent,      useAsDefault: true },
        { path: '/market', name: 'Market', component: marketComponent },
    ])
    export class AppComponent  {
    constructor(private _http: geoService) { }

    public maps;
    public cat_error: Boolean = false;
    public xml_Latitude :string;
    public xml_Lang: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition);
        } else {
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
        var input: any = document.getElementById('google_places_ac');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {});
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function  ()     {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            console.log(place)
        });
    }

    showPosition(position) {
        this.xml_Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        this.xml_Lang = position.coords.longitude;

        this._http.getPlaces(this.xml_Latitude, this.xml_Lang).subscribe(
            data => { this.maps = data },
            err => { this.cat_error = true }
        );

        var result = this.maps.results;
        var city = result[0].address_components[4].long_name + "," + result[0].address_components[6].long_name;
        alert(city);


    }  
}
```

and geoservice file

```
 import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
    import { Response, Jsonp} from 'angular2/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class geoService {

    constructor(private http: Jsonp) { }

    public xml_Latitude: string;
    public xml_Lang: string;

    public getPlaces(xml_Latitude, xml_Lang) {
        return this.http.get(`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=
                            '${this.xml_Latitude}','${this.xml_Lang}'&sensor=true`)
                .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                .catch(this.handleError);
        }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
            console.error(error);
            return error.json().error || 'Server error';
        }
    }
```

error also says getplaces is not a function, I think I am missing something but don't know what....

Comment: What property is undefined? Please add the concrete error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the callback ordering problem identified by Thierry, you have a lost `this` context on this line:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition);
```

### The Problem

You have the classic JavaScript problem known as the *incorrect `this` context*.
The [`this` keyword in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) behaves differently than in does in other languages like C# and Java.

#### How `this` works

The `this` keyword, in a function, is determined as follows:
 * If the function was created through a call to `.bind`, the `this` value is the argument provided to `bind`
 * If the function was *invoked* through a method call, e.g. `expr.func(args)`, then `this` is `expr`
 * Otherwise
   * If the code is in [*strict mode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), `this` is `undefined`
   * Otherwise, `this` is `window` (in a browser)

Let's look at how this works in practice:

```
class Foo {
    value = 10;
    doSomething() {
        // Prints 'undefined', not '10'
        console.log(this.value);
    }
}
let f = new Foo();
window.setTimeout(f.doSomething, 100);
```

This code will print `undefined` (or, in strict mode, throw an exception).
This is because we ended up in the last branch of the decision tree above.
The `doSomething` function was invoked, the function wasn't a result of a `bind` call, and it wasn't invoked in a method syntax position.

We can't see the code for `setTimeout` to see what its invocation looks like, but we don't need to.
Something to realize is that all `doSomething` methods point to *the same function object*.
In other words:

```
let f1 = new Foo();
let f2 = new Foo();
// 'true'
console.log(f1.doSomething === f2.doSomething);
```

We know that `setTimeout` can only see the function we passed it, so when it invokes that function,
  there's no way for it to know which `this` to provide.
The `this` context has been lost due to our *referencing* the method without *invoking* it.

#### The Red Flag

Once you know about `this` problems, they're easy to spot:

```
class Foo {
    value = 10;
    method1() {
        doSomething(this.method2); // DANGER, method reference without invocation
    }   
    method2() {
        console.log(this.value);
    }
}
```

### The Solution

You have a few options here, each with its own trade-offs.
The best option depends on how often the method in question is invoked from differing call sites.

#### Arrow Function in Class Definition

Instead of using the normal method syntax, use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to initialize a per-instance member.

```
class DemonstrateScopingProblems {
    private status = "blah";

    public run = () => {
        // OK
        console.log(this.status);
    }
}
let d = new DemonstrateScopingProblems();
window.setTimeout(d.run); // OK
```

- Good/bad: This creates an additional closure per method per instance of your class. If this method is usually only used in regular method calls, this is overkill. However, if it's used a lot in callback positions, it's more efficient for the class instance to capture the `this` context instead of each call site creating a new closure upon invoke.
- Good: Impossible for external callers to forget to handle `this` context
- Good: Typesafe in TypeScript
- Good: No extra work if the function has parameters
- Bad: Derived classes can't call base class methods written this way using `super.`
- Bad: The exact semantics of which methods are "pre-bound" and which aren't create an additional non-typesafe contract between your class and its consumers.

#### Function Expression at Reference Site

Shown here with some dummy parameters for explanatory reasons:

```
class DemonstrateScopingProblems {
    private status = "blah";

    public something() {
        console.log(this.status);
    }

    public run(x: any, y: any) {
        // OK
        console.log(this.status + ': ' + x + ',' + y);
    }
}
let d = new DemonstrateScopingProblems();
// With parameters
someCallback((n, m) => d.run(n, m));
// Without parameters
window.setTimeout(() => d.something(), 100);
```

- Good/bad: Opposite memory/performance trade-off compared to the first method
- Good: In TypeScript, this has 100% type safety
- Good: Works in ECMAScript 3
- Good: You only have to type the instance name once
- Bad: You'll have to type the parameters twice
- Bad: Doesn't easily work with variadic parameters

Comment: wow .. thanks for this great explanation , i wil give it a try and let you know

Comment: wow you just solved my problem i changeed the function now its working and getting a response , the only thing is i am not able to extract the result i.e. this line is not working can you suggest anything?  var result = this.maps.results; // <----------
          var city = result[0].address_components[4].long_name + "," + result[0].address_components[6].long_name;
          a

Comment: Please ask a new question. Comments is not intended for follow-up problems.

Comment: hi can you help me with this question? i am not getting any answers.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386414/typescript-logic-issue-with-angular-2-and-google-maps-api

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should move the `result` block into the subscribe callback associated the getPlaces method call:

```
showPosition(position) {
    this.xml_Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    this.xml_Lang = position.coords.longitude;

    this._http.getPlaces(this.xml_Latitude, this.xml_Lang).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.maps = data;

          var result = this.maps.results; // <----------
          var city = result[0].address_components[4].long_name + "," + result[0].address_components[6].long_name;
          alert(city);
        },
        err => { this.cat_error = true }
    );
}
```

It's because `this.maps` is undefined before the callback is called. And you try tyo get the `result` attribute before (`this.maps.results`).

**Edit**

I also see a problem at the line `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`. You could refactor your code this way:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => { // <----
    this.showPosition(position);
  });
} else {
  alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
}
```

Comment: moving it didnt work..  if i dont create a service and get the httpservice inside this class and call for the get function and notmaping anything it still throws error for get property.. even if i use http rather than jsonp same problem

Comment: Oh there is another problem at line: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`. I updated my answer...

Comment: actually this will again create 'this' problem i just changed it to res=>{then function and in inside it res.coord.lat ...} ... but thanks for the help  kudos...

Comment: Really? The `showPosition` method is now executed in the context of the component (`this` == component instance). So `this._http` in this method isn't now undefined...

Comment: yes and the reason is i didnt use this for navigator instance so its not conflicting with component instance. its the javascript problem you should read the explanation above its good.