# value not updating in the view after data update , angular2 and typescript

Tags: typescript, angular

this is my `ngOnInit` function

```
 instance.input = document.getElementById('google_places_ac');
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(instance.input, { types: ['(cities)']});
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            instance.setValue(place.address_components[3].long_name, place.address_components[2].long_name, place.address_components[1].long_name);

         });
```

and this is my `setValue()` function

```
public setValue(a,b,c) {
    this.coutnry = a;
    this.state = b;
    this.city = c;
    this.sharedService.country = this.coutnry;
    this.sharedService.city = this.city;
    this.sharedService.state = this.state;
    console.log(a, b, c);
}
```

and below is my html template to show and get the values

```
 <input id="google_places_ac" attr.state="{{state}}" attr.country="{{coutnry}}" name="google_places_ac" type="text" value="{{city}}" class="form-control" />
```

the problem is my html attributes not getting updated once `place_changed` function is called,is there anything i have to do to get updated values on view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check this angular2 official docs for setting up the attributes,

cheatsheet - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cheatsheet.html

```
<input id="google_places_ac" [attr.state]="state" [attr.country]="coutnry"
name="google_places_ac" type="text" value="{{city}}" class="form-control" />
```

---

**Update**

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from 'angular2/core';

constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {
}
public setValue(a,b,c) {
    this.coutnry = a;
    this.state = b;
    this.city = c;
    this.sharedService.country = this.coutnry;
    this.sharedService.city = this.city;
    this.sharedService.state = this.state;
    console.log(a, b, c);
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: i changed console.log to    console.log(this.coutnry, this.state, this.city); this its showing proper values but no update on the view

Comment: This could be changeDetection problem or ngZone problem. Check my udpdated answer.

Comment: yes dude... thank a lot for enlightening me with changedetection :)

Comment: hey i just got a follow up problem , how can i detect changes on child element from parent , the event is fired from parent component and child component is in route-outlet getting value from shared service , can you help me?

Comment: you can use ChangeDetectorRef in individual component.

Comment: but when can i fire that detection as i can not bind it to anything its fired from parent only

Comment: I'm not sure how you have implemented everything. But I guess in child component within `ngOnChanges` hook you can use.

Comment: @micronyks haven't look at code..as it has been fired from `outer context` of A2.. +1 for core problem of change detection

Comment: hi i created this question please share your expertise and help me on change detection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388981/change-detection-in-angular2-using-shared-service

Answer (score 1):

You should use property binding by wrapping attribute inside `[]`

```
<input id="google_places_ac" [attr.state]="state" [attr.country]="coutnry" 
 name="google_places_ac" type="text" [value]="city" class="form-control" />
```

Additional thing is, you made typo while writing `country` like you wrote`coutnry` instead in two places.

```
this.sharedService.country = this.coutnry; //in constructor

attr.country="{{coutnry}}" //second place
```

Comment: when i do that i get thi long error Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{state}}]  and this for all attrs. i am calling this function in ngOnInit

Comment: @Ironsun are you sure you change you code to my udpated answer?

Comment: `Eagle eyes` @PankajParkar

Comment: ok i was using {{}} but now not getting the error but still values not updating

Comment: @Ironsun could you debug and confirm that `setValue` function is setting `state` & other value correctly?

Comment: i changed console.log to console.log(this.coutnry, this.state, this.city); this its showing proper values but no update on the view –

Comment: @Ironsun are you reading value of attribute from `DOM` directly, and they are getting undefined.. or you are never getting their value in DOM? I wanted to know how you are verifying it that value has populated..

Comment: i am checking the code - inspect element thing, and at first i have a navigator function in constructor which sets location at the strat before binding this function should i add it to the question for your reference?