# change detection in angular2 using shared service

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

i am having a parent function `ngOnInit()` which gets the value from google maps as follow

```
instance.input = document.getElementById('google_places_ac');
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(instance.input, { types: ['(cities)']});
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            instance.setValue(place.address_components[3].long_name, place.address_components[2].long_name, place.address_components[1].long_name);

        });
```

`setValue()` is function which shares value with shared service and on html page i have same thing as follow on parent and child
`<input id="google_places_ac" [(attr.state)]="state" [(attr.country)]="coutnry" name="google_places_ac" type="text" value="{{city}}" class="form-control" />`

in parent component class i fire changedetection on `setValue()` function

```
   setValue(a, b, c) {
        this.coutnry = a;
        this.state = b;
        this.city = c;
        this.sharedService.country = this.coutnry;
        this.sharedService.city = this.city;
        this.sharedService.state = this.state;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      //  console.log(this.coutnry, this.state, this.city);
    }
```

this works well on parent but change is not happening on child , i created a click function which fires the changedetection on child which works too but i want it to fire automaticaly from parent is there any workaround for it?

Comment: I am already in d bed. So cant help you atm. But if you are using sharedservice, same way you can use sharedobject. So when parent view is changed, service's shared object will be updated and so every view connected to that object will get updated.

Comment: There is no two-way binding for attributes `[(attr.state)]="state"`. This is only supported for properties (input and output) ´[(state)]="state"`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer ohh thanks for the information.bdw i am still facing a problem with this question i am not able to get the data when route page is loaded . it works when page is rendered with parent or once the page is loaded and i change text in parent field but it doesnt show data on start when the page is rendered first , can you suggest anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it comes to sharing a global object between components, it is better to use global shared service combined with `Rxjs` `observable design pattern`. Here is the code, **You should configure it according to yours**:

First, your global shared service should look like this:

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";
@Injectable()
export class SearchService {

private _searchText = new Subject<string>();

public searchTextStream$ = this._searchText.asObservable();

broadcastTextChange(text:string) {
    this._searchText.next(text);
    }
}
```

Second,you inject your `service` into your `parent component`

```
...
constructor(private _searchService:SearchService) {
...
```

Third, add to the `providers` list of your parent component or higher component the service, because this service should the same **instance** between subscribed components, **This part is very important**:

```
providers: [SearchService,...]
```

Then when you want to `broadcast` new change you call `broadcastTextChange` with a new value as follows:

```
...
this._searchService.broadcastTextChange("newTextHere");
...
```

Then inside your `the child component` you inject the same `service` and subscribe to it:

```
this._searchService.searchTextStream$.subscribe(
        text => {
            // This text is a new text from parent component.
            this.localText = text;
            //Add your own logic here if you need.
        }
    )
```

Comment: thanks for the long answer will give it a try and let you know

Comment: hi i am facing a problem with solution , change detection doesnt happen when routing , it works if my child page is open at the time of parents rendering but not if i call it later via routing, am i missing something??

Comment: Could you move your shared service on a providers list of your root component, which has <router-outlet> directive ?

Comment: i can but thats not parent my structure is like this parent > child > child but i will give it a try to broadcast message oninit will let you know

Comment: -i subscribed to the service in mid child and again brodcasted the message but not caught by last child, should i add it to provider and create a new instance or is there any other way?

Comment: not working even if i create new instance of service, should i create a middle layer of service???

Comment: is there limitation of angular 2 that i can not pass value to all the childs on route ?

Comment: ok one thing you need to know is that when page is rendered its not showing the data but as soon as i change the text in parent field it changes

Comment: but when i am on same page is renders data from parent to child and when routing it doesnt render data oninit , if i kepp isloading false untill subscribe function is done then it just shows loading like forever

Comment: BehaviorSubject might be a better choice for some. If your child component subscribes too late, it will not catch the latest 'change'