# Angular 2 - send textarea value to a shared component

Tags: angular, data-binding, binding, components

I have a textarea in the first page and when i go to next page i need this value to show in a notepad component that is shared in the next pages but at the same time i need that when i write new info in the shared component first and new information can be saved and displayed. i need to use angular2 and i cant use any stuff from github.enter image description here

[image: the textarea]
[image: the shared coomponent]

Comment: How are they related the firs and second component. The are children to some parent component?

Comment: that first component is part of the form in that page, the form is a a component but not shared, they arent children to other page. my main problem is get the info from the notepad and pass to next pages.

Comment: Try with defining property `someProp`and then assign that property to both of them with `[(ngModel)]="someProp"`. You add it like this `<input [(ngModel)]="someProp" placeholder="Picture URL" type="text">`

Comment: you can try `BehaviourSubject` see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36404541/behavioursubject-in-angular2-how-it-works-and-how-to-use-it) , if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its not a parent-child relation, you can use shared service and pass the `textarea` value using `setter` and `getter`.

Example:

form.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'form1-component',
  template: `
    <h3>Form 1</h3>
        <textarea [(ngModel)]="input"></textarea>
        <button (click)="save(input)">Save</button>
  `,
})
export class Form1 {
  input: any;

  constructor(private appState: AppState){

  }

  save(val){
    this.appState.setData(val);
  }
}
```

shared.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppState {
  public formData;

  setData(value){
    this.formData = value;
  }

  getData(){
    return this.formData;
  }
}
```

other.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'summary',
  template: `
    <h3>Summary From Form 1</h3>
    <div>{{data}}</div>
  `,
})
export class Summary {
  data: any;

  constructor(private appState: AppState){
    this.data = this.appState.getData();
  }
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/7xF6qVLXNT2pGrFz1Clf?p=preview)

Comment: If it resolved your problem, please mark it as 'Accepted'  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Input` decorator if there is parent child relationship between components. Else make use of `Services` or `BehaviourSubject`. These are the following approaches based on priority:

1. Using Services(Most Recommended).
2. Using Behavior Subjects from RxJS library.
3. Use Redux for state management.
4. Using browser storage(session/local) but least recommended as prone
   to data security.

Comment: any chance to make  a plunker example using services?

Comment: You can yourself create a service and set the variable in setter function. Other components which use the same service can get the value of a variable using getter function.

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies with ReactiveFormsModules, only saving to cookies when you have valid data.

```
npm install cookies-js --save
```

app-module.ts

```
...
imports: [ReactiveFormsModule]
...
```

MyComponent.html

```
...
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input name="a" formControlName="b">
</form>
...
```

MyComponent.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup,FormBuilder,Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import * as Cookies from 'cookies-js';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit{

  private static readonly COOKIE_DATA = 'data_to_save';

  form : FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

     this.form.fb.group({
     b: ['' Validators.required] 
     });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    const data = Cookies.get(MyComponent.COOKIE_DATA);
    if (data) {
      this.form.setValue(JSON.parse(data));
    }
    this.form.valueChanges
     .filter(() => this.form.valid)
     .do(validData => Cookies.set(COOKIE_DATA, JSON.stringify(validData)
     .subscribe()
  }
}
```