# Angular 4 bind checkbox to array in *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to add an item to an array whenever a check box is checked in *ngFor I am looking for a neat way of doing this without too much code or using a component method. I know this used to be really easy in angular version 1

```
<tr *ngFor="let this_user of RoleUsers.Users">
    ...
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [(ngModel)]="UsersToRemove.Users[this_user.id]" /> <!--[(ngModel)]="" --> <!-- ng-false-value="expression"-->
    ..
</tr>
```

For this code I get the error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '13' of undefined` so I think I am very close.

At the moment I am using the user ids to track the keys but if I could have a nice array. If this is not possible without a component method please provide an example.

**Update**
I have managed to get this working with fewer code;

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" (change)="AddOrRemoveUser(this_user, $event.target.checked)" />
```

Then the method;

```
AddOrRemoveUserToRemove (user, checked) {
    console.log ("Remove or add: ", user, checked);
}
```

I think this this the quickest way to do it.

The UsersToRemove object looks like this;

```
class UsersToRemove {
    Users: any[];
    InAction: boolean = false;
}
```

This is attached to the actual component.

Comment: Can you post the Typescript for UsersToRemove.Users... At a glance that appears to be a static from you use of upper/lower case...

Comment: Best practice to work with form is to use reactive form. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms I advise you to found in this direction.

Comment: This is just a table not a form. It has just 1 checkbox in a loop and a "Remove selected" button. I think that will be more work to use reactive forms

Comment: right so you'd have needed an instance of UsersToRemove and call this.instance.Users[this_user_id] to bind to [(ngModel)] surely.

Comment: That does not work. I get the error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '13' of undefined`

Comment: because you have class not an instance.. i.e. no new statement in ngInit... to be able to call this.<instance name> and the instance name not class should have been in the input element to rhs of = after banana box [(ngModel)] And sometimes you can try elvis operator this.<instance name>?.property in case something odd is going on too..

Comment: You mean I should add; ` [(ngModel)]="this.instance.Users[this_user_id]"` ?

Comment: No... I'm assuming you've not inlined the html... you can call it usersToRemove = new UsersToRemove() even as a property above constructor and avoid ngInit if you like. Then in html use [(ngModel)]="usersToRemove?.Users[this_user]" (optionally add ? Elvis operator)

Comment: @JGFMK That worked which what I was looking for originally. But when I check a user with an id of 45. I get dirty array with length 45. Which is not a problem since it has just 1 element 45: true. So my problem was not having;  UsersToRemove: UsersToRemove = new UsersToRemove ()

Comment: Well the @Smiranin comment about using reactive-forms allows you to deal with stale data detection. If/when you make transition to convert code be sure to add ReactiveFormsModule instead of FormsModule to your app-module.ts. That caught me out initially. I gave a bit of an incite to it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165079/angular-2-send-textarea-value-to-a-shared-component/45166499#45166499 But there's far more to it than that...

Comment: Why can't I use this;  [(ngModel)]="UsersToRemove.Users[]" Is there something equivalent to this?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me but with too much code. Just to answer my question;

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class RoleUsersComponent implements OnInit {
    ..
    UsersToRemove: UsersToRemove = new UsersToRemove
  constructor(
     ...
  ) {
        ...
  }

  ...

    AddOrRemoveUser (user, checked) {
        if (checked==true){
            this.UsersToRemove.AddUser(user)
        }else {
            this.UsersToRemove.RemoveUser(user)
        }
        console.log ("UsersToRemove: ", this.UsersToRemove.Users)
    }
}

class UsersToRemove {
    Users: any[];
    constructor( ) { this.Users = []; }
    InAction: boolean = false;
    AddUser (user): void {
        if (!this.UserExists(user)){
            this.Users.push(user);
        }
    }
    RemoveUser (user): void {
        for (var _i = 0; _i < this.Users.length; _i++) {
            if (this.Users[_i].id==user.id){
                this.Users.splice( _i, 1 )
            }
        }
    }
    UserExists (user): boolean {
        let exists = false;
        for (var _i = 0; _i < this.Users.length; _i++) {
            if (this.Users[_i].id==user.id){
                exists = true;
            }
        }
        return exists;
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let this_user of RoleUsers.Users">
  ...
  <th scope="row" *ngIf="UsersToRemove.InAction">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" (change)="AddOrRemoveUser (this_user, $event.target.checked)" /> <!--[(ngModel)]="" --> <!-- ng-false-value="expression"-->
      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    </label>
  </th>
  ...
</tr>
```