# Angular 2 : how to populate a dropdown list from a json file with my service?

Tags: angular, typescript, service, dropdown, populate

I have a service :

```
@Injectable()
export class LostFoundEditService {
    public lostForm: FormGroup;
    public countries: any[] = [];
    private countriesUrl = 'assets/countries.json';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    init() {
        this.initForm();

        this.http.get(this.countriesUrl).subscribe(data => {
            this.countries = this.countries.concat(data['countries']);
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
    }

    private initForm() {
        this.lostForm = new FormGroup({
            'title': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            'description': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            'country': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            'state': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            'city': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            'zipCode': new FormControl(''),
            'street': new FormControl('')
        });
    }
}
```

and a class thats uses this service :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-lost-edit',
  templateUrl: './lost-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lost-edit.component.css']
})
export class LostEditComponent implements OnInit {
  lostForm: FormGroup;
  countries: any[] = [];
  states: any[] = [];
  cities: any[] = [];

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private lostFoundEditService: LostFoundEditService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lostFoundEditService.init();
    this.lostForm = this.lostFoundEditService.lostForm;
    this.countries = this.lostFoundEditService.countries;
  }

  onCancel() {
  }
```

}

Also I have the template associated with that class :

```
(...)
                  <select
                    id="country"
                    formControlName="country"
                    class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Countries</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let country of countries" value="{{country['id']}}">{{country['name']}}</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          (...)
```

My question is : how to wait for the end of subscribe method (in `init()` of `LostFoundEditService`) to have all countries of the json file entered in `countries` array of `LostEditComponent`. Nothing appears in the dropdown list for the moment...

Comment: you should be initializing the form inside the subscribe

Comment: `public countries: Observable<any[]>`
in init()
     `this.countries =  this.http.get(this.countriesUrl).map(data=> data['countries'])`

      and in html:
`<option *ngFor="let country of countries | async" value="{{country['id']}}">{{country['name']}}</option>` It's better to avoid subscribing as much as possible. Angular's Async pipe handles subscribing for you

Comment: @Aravind With that it gives me an error : formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in. It seems that the form is not initialized...

Comment: you could make the init() return this.http.get(this.countriesUrl); after the initForm(). then in the LostEditComponent you can do the this.lostFoundEditService.init().subscribe(data => { // set countries property in here after you get the data });

Comment: @SebOlens It gives me compilation error : property map does not exist on type Observable<Object> ...

Comment: @MolikMiah I don't want to externalize all my service code into my component, in that way it works but I don't want that...

Comment: you need to import the map operator than
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` in the file where you're using it

Comment: ok, in that case an alternative would be to make your countries in your service a BehaviourSubject and then from your component you can subscribe to that property so that when it changes the countries array in your component can be set/updated. please look here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36404625/1876576

Comment: @SebOlens thanks for your knowledgement, that way it works.

Comment: @simslay No problem :) When I have time I'll write an answer so others can see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly try this.

What i'm doing here is changing the countries property from an Array to a BehaviourSubject which means your component can subscribe to this property. We can subscribe by using the async pipe in your template which in the angular world calls the subscribe.

In your service, when we finish getting the data via the subscribe you can set the value by doing this.countries.next(data['countries']).

service :

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class LostFoundEditService {
    public lostForm: FormGroup;
    public countries: Subject = new BehaviorSubject<Array<any>>(null);
    private countriesUrl = 'assets/countries.json';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    init() {
        this.initForm();

        this.http.get(this.countriesUrl).subscribe(data => {
            this.countries.next(this.countries.concat(data['countries']));
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
    }

    private initForm() {
        this.lostForm = new FormGroup({
            'title': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            'description': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            'country': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            'state': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            'city': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            'zipCode': new FormControl(''),
            'street': new FormControl('')
        });
    }
}
```

component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-lost-edit',
  templateUrl: './lost-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lost-edit.component.css']
})
export class LostEditComponent implements OnInit {
  lostForm: FormGroup;
  countries;
  states: any[] = [];
  cities: any[] = [];

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private lostFoundEditService: LostFoundEditService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lostFoundEditService.init();
    this.lostForm = this.lostFoundEditService.lostForm;
    this.countries = this.lostFoundEditService.countries;
  }

  onCancel() {
  }
```

}

template :

```
(...)
                  <select
                    id="country"
                    formControlName="country"
                    class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Countries</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let country of countries | async" value="{{country['id']}}">{{country['name']}}</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          (...)
```